# AdMob via MoPub - Not enough space to show ad

Tags: android, admob, mopub

I don't know why this is happening and it's driving me mad. Long story short, out of all the ad networks I use via MoPub, AdMob seems to be the only one that doesn't display an advert, claiming it doesn't have enough space. In MoPub I have a phone ad unit and a tablet ad unit. Here's the  specific log:

```
02-10 09:44:44.094: I/Ads(9363): Request scenario: Online server request.
02-10 09:44:50.114: D/webviewglue(9363): nativeDestroy view: 0x678b8418
02-10 09:44:50.124: I/Ads(9363): onReceiveAd()
02-10 09:44:50.124: D/MoPub(9363): Google AdMob load succeeded. Showing ad...
02-10 09:44:50.124: D/MoPub(9363): adLoaded
02-10 09:44:50.124: D/MoPub(9363): Tracking impression for native adapter.
02-10 09:44:50.144: W/Ads(9363): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <969, 119>, Has: <800, 1073741823>
02-10 09:44:50.144: W/Ads(9363): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <969, 119>, Has: <800, 1073741823>
```

The ad gets loaded but not displayed because apparently it needs more space. I only want to display banner ads. I'm testing on a Nexus 7.

The other networks I use are LeadBolt and Millennial. They display banner ads just fine in the same space.

My java code to select which ad unit to show (phone or tablet based on screen size):

```
    //Advert if statement
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

            if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
                            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                    //Tablet
                    mAdViewTabletLarge = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.LargeAdvert);
                            mAdViewTabletLarge.setAdUnitId("id here");
                            mAdViewTabletLarge.setVisibility(Application.getAdVisibiltyForEdition(this.getApplicationContext()));
                            mAdViewTabletLarge.loadAd();
            }
            else if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
                                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
                    //Tablet
                    mAdViewTabletXLarge = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.LargeAdvert);
                            mAdViewTabletXLarge.setAdUnitId("id here");
                            mAdViewTabletXLarge.setVisibility(Application.getAdVisibiltyForEdition(this.getApplicationContext()));
                            mAdViewTabletXLarge.loadAd();
            }
            else {
                    //Phone
                    mAdViewPhone = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.LargeAdvert);
                            mAdViewPhone.setAdUnitId("id here");
                            mAdViewPhone.setVisibility(Application.getAdVisibiltyForEdition(this.getApplicationContext()));
                            mAdViewPhone.loadAd();
            }
```

Anyone got any clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Silly question, but how much space *does* it have? If it doesn't have 969x119, it's simply not going to show. According to the log, you have 800 horizontal(not enough), and some random overflow-looking number for the vertical. What does logging `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` reveal?

Comment: To clarify, AdMob is pickier about it than other networks. Others will still serve the ad and let the app scale it or not. AdMob wants stricter adherence to their rules/guidelines.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't have enough space but then for a banner ad I can't see why it is requesting such a big advert. In MoPub I set tablet adverts to be 728x90. That's the only control I have over it. For something that big I guess I'll never have enough space, maybe on a 10inch tablet but not 7inch tablets.

Comment: True, you may not, depending on resolution. You may want to check the space available, also, and maybe have a separate ad unit for "big, but not AdMob big" tablets. I agree it sucks, but us poor devs only have so much control over advertising.

Comment: Well AdMob is being the anomaly here so at worst I can just get rid of that and try another network. Of course I could always just set the ad unit to be a normal 350x50, something I've been thinking about, less intrusive and all that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because a 728x90 dp advert is too big on a Nexus 7 in portrait mode, which is only 600 dp wide. I can't imagine how other networks are making a 728x90 image fit into 600x90, unless they're scaling the height down to keep aspect ratio. AdMob doesn't scale ads like that, and instead throws this warning.

It sounds like a Mopub limitation that tablet adverts can only be one size. I'm not familiar with the Mopub front-end setup, but maybe you could create a second advert with a smaller size for 7" tablets, and check your screen width at runtime to determine which advert to show.

Comment: I can imagine that being the case. The other adverts don't scale, the adverts don't fit on the screen. I know I shouldn't be allowing that but as you say, MoPub only allows one size which is a shame. Anyway I've scaled it back so the 728x90 adverts will only show on 10inch tablets from now on and 350x50 phone adverts will show on the nexus 7. Not ideal but oh well. My next issue is figuring out why clicking on a millennial advert does absolutely nothing. Problem after problem!

Comment: For 7" tablets, a more appropriate size is 468x60. I'm a little surprised Mopub doesn't offer that. Re: Millennial, I happen to have a possible explanation for that as well. You're probably testing on a device with API 17 or 18. They have some issue on their end where clicking their ads after API 16 does nothing.

Comment: Yeah my Nexus 7 is an API 17 device. Sort of relieved that it's not my end. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Im getting the same problem on my Nexus 7.I am currently using Eclipse Juno, Service Release 1. In this version there are @dimension/...
references automatically added to xml layout files.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
   ...
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   ...
   ...
```

When I remove the @dimension/... references, the error goes away, and the ad shows. Not sure  if there is a trick to override the error, and allow the ad to show within the @dimension/...parameters. If anyone knows, please share!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a 320x50 ad unit and a 728x90 ad unit in MoPub, detect the width of the device, and then conditionally fire them depending on the width of your device.

If the screen width is less than 728 pixels, fire off the 320x50 ad unit.

If it is greater, use the leaderboard ad unit.

Comment: Yeah that was my original idea but I found the LARGE - XLARGE conditionals easier. While trying to debug these issues I've learnt how to grab the screen width of a device and write if statements on it so I will be updating my code.

Comment: I just realised that is even that wont work since admob is asking for a device width of 969. I could leave it the way it is or call it so that if the width is above 970, it should show the tablet advert. 7Inch tabets will have a device width over 728 so the same problem will occur.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error:

The view where you're trying to show ads is deleted from the parent view.
be sure that

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutAdmobGame"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="52dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

This within its parent view and has not been removed